# Best practice to build a BST from a Binary Tree

Tags: java, inheritance, binary-search-tree, inner-classes

Im creating a Binary Search Tree in Java extending from a Binary Tree already implemented, but it does not work when I try to use some inherited methods. Let me explain:

**Binary Tree:**

```
public class BinaryTree<T>{
     private Node<T> root;

     public class Node<T>{
          T value;
          Node left;
          Node right;

          public Node(T value){
               this.value = value;
               this.left = null;
               this.right = null;
          }
     }
     
     public BinaryTree(){
          ...
     }
     public void printInOrder(){
          ...
     }  
 }
```

**BST:**

```
public class BST extends BinaryTree<Integer>{
      private Node<Integer> root;

      public BST(Integer v){
          super(v);
      }

      public void insert(Integer element){
            insert(this.root, element);
      }

      private insert( Node node, Integer element){
            if(node == null)
               return;
        
            if(node.value > value) {
                  if(node.left != null) {
                       insert(node.left, value);
                  }
                  else {
                       node.left = new NodeBST(value);
                  }
             }else { // Node.value < element
                 if(node.right != null) {
                      insert(node.right, value);
                 }
                 else {
                      node.right = new NodeBST(value);
                 }
             }

         }

   }
```

**App:**

```
public class App{

      public static void main(String[] args){
             BST bst = new BST(4);
             bst.insert(2);
             bst.insert(5);
             bst.insert(3);
             bst.insert(7);

             bst.printInOrder();  //Here I got the problem

     }
}
```

If I try to print it, it will just print the root (4) and will be null for the rest of the nodes. When I look what's going on inside, it turns out there is two roots:

- **BST.Node root**, which contains all the nodes in the proper order
- **BinaryTree.Node root**, which just contains the root and all the other nodes are null.

So I guess it creates the root correctly because I'm calling the super class in the BST' constructor, but when I creates a new Node in the *insert method*, it only appends it in BST.Node root (and not in the BinaryTree.Node root), therefore when I call *print*, which is implemented in BinaryTree, from BST in prints null :/

So my questios are:

- How can I get to use the *print method* from BST in order to print all the values in BST.Node root?
- What does prevent BinaryTree.Node root to be the same as BST.Node root?
- What would be the best practice to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare 'root' a second time in BST, it shadows the 'root' in the base class.

Either make 'root' in BinaryTree protected or provide the necessary accessors there, so subclasses can use it.